# open several directories from the terminal as tabs inside a single file manager window

Tags: command-line, nautilus, file-manager

I want to open several directories from the terminal as tabs inside a single Nautilus window. If Nautilus cannot be used then I want to know what GUI based file explorer can open directories in different tabs. If no GUI based file manager can do it, I want to know what text based managers can open multiple tabs.

If no alternatives exist, I wan't to know why do you people prefer opening tabs with the mouse, is it the best investment of our time? I need an answer because for a certain project I want to open a certain amount of tabs without doing it like machine each time I open my file manager.

To start you up, doing this:

```
$ nautilus path1 path2
```

, will open two nautilus windows instead of one nautilus window containing two tabs.

Comment: [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/26042/can-a-single-nautilus-window-be-started-with-multiple-tabs) might help you.

Comment: yea, i saw that a few months back. i don't like complicating my life with too many scripts, but good to know it is an option. i will rephrase my question a bit

Comment: I haven't much experience with nautilus in particular, but bookmarks are a common feature of GUI file explorers. Are those unsatisfactory for your task?

Comment: Bookmarks only open one tab per click. What I want is to configure project scripts and open nautilus from the terminal. Most of what I do is on the terminal and automated to increase my productivity. I work in resarch/support so I have to fast switch between multiple projects, but who wouldn't want his "workspace" (programs, editors, even browser tabs) restored in a matter of seconds?